# First time app Xcode 10 and iOS not running

Tags: ios, xcode

It has been a while since a developed an APP for iOS. So, I reinstalled everything.

Xcode 10 and created an empty single app view. When I clicked run to make install and run the app on my phone I got this error:

> Could not locate device support files.
>
> This iPhone 8 Plus (Model A1864, A1897, A1898, A1899) is running iOS 12.1.2 (16C101), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

What step am I missing?

**Update**

After "unpairing / paring" everything seemed fine, I ran the app but when I got the final step asked to restart the phone, so I did. I go the same error again after restart but now I had this screen for a while:

[image]

And like 10 minutes later I go this:

[image]

Worth mentioning I see the app installed in phone, I just can't run it from Xcode because when I do I get the first error above.

Comment: could you please unpair the device and pair again ?

Comment: Xcode Menu -> Window -> Device & Simulator -> Right click on your device listed on the left menu.
NB: Device must be connected in order to device appear on the list.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you running? If you are truly running Xcode 10, you need to upgrade to Xcode 10.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use iOS 12.1.2 you must be using Xcode version 10.1 or higher. Xcode versions tend to stay aligned with iOS versions. So Xcode 10 refers to iOS 12.0.x, Xcode 10.1 refers to iOS 12.1.x, etc.

Ensuring that you are updated to the latest version of Xcode should fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try **Unpair** and re **Pair** the device.

To Unpair the device, connect the device

> Xcode Top Menu -> Window -> Device & Simulator

Now right click on the listed device & unpair.

For pairing, just reconnect the phone, and trust when the prompt occurs.

**Visual Guide**
[image]
[image]

Comment: It seemed to worked. When I ran the first time all seemed to worked find and at the very asked to restart the phone, so I did. After restart the error came back and pop up window appeared saying "Downloading 1 item "